# Can we use algolia search with access level permissions

Tags: javascript, algolia

We are looking to use Algolia Search for an application. We like the convenience of Algolia but are stuck on one point. We have custom user groups and each user group can only see a subset of the records. When we are pushing records to Algolia all the records show up. How do we pair that with our custom logic of specific users can see specific records and we dont those to show up on the search lists.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this use case is to encode the permission information directly inside your records (like a group or a user). You can for example add a permission array on your record:

```
"permission": ["group1", "user42"]
```

You then just need to add this permission attribute in the list of attributes for faceting and apply the restriction in your query via a facetFilters argument.

I would also recommend to use the [secured-API key](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/security/api-keys/#secured-api-keys) feature that allows to apply this restriction in a secure way even if the query come from a browser or mobile app. A HMAC-SHA 256 signature is computed in your backend between the API key and the restriction to ensure no-one can change this restriction.